# Python 3: Optimizing summation over scipy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, scipy

I am currently working on a problem, where I have to do sums over specific entries of scipy/numpy arrays and I am looking for a way to get completely rid of all the Python for loops. I am using Python 3.3 on Mac OS X. Below is an example of one of the sums I am doing and for the example's sake, I sum over the entries of an array filled with random integers.

```
from scipy import ones, conjugate, sum, random

n = 5
M = random.randint(5,size=(4*n**2,4*n**2))
H = sum((M[i+1,:2*n**2]*M[i,:2*n**2].conjugate()).sum() * (-M[i,:2*n**2]*M[i+1,:2*n**2].conjugate()).sum() for i in range(0,2*n**2,2))
```

I first calculate the product of two matrix entries and then sum over half of the columns. This I do twice and then sum over half of the rows in steps of two.

This might look weird, but I am working with a Hamiltonian for a system on a lattice, where each row corresponds to a certain lattice point and even and odd rows stand for spin up or down. n will eventually be big and I need to speed this summation up a bit.

Now, I am not able to figure out, how I can get rid of the for loop. I tried to do it with a range()-argument in the row index, but that didn't get me the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it just me, or are you only using a quarter of the array?

Comment: Yeah, I get the array by diagonalizing a matrix and M corresponds to the matrix filled with the eigenvectors. I transformed the sums already such that the loops are the shortest. Other sums will use different part of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you can do

```
H_bis = np.sum(M[1:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2] * M[:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2].conjugate(), axis=1)
H_bis = H_bis * H_bis.conjugate()
H_bis = -np.sum(H_bis)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
# We need a complex test case to make sure the conjugate works properly
M = (random.randint(5,size=(4*n**2,4*n**2)) +
     random.randint(5,size=(4*n**2,4*n**2))*1j)

H_bis = np.sum(M[1:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2] * M[:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2].conjugate(),
               axis=-1)
H_bis *= np.sum(-M[:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2] * M[1:2*n**2:2, :2*n**2].conjugate(),
                axis=-1)
H_bis = np.sum(H_bis)
>>> np.allclose(H, H_bis)
True
```

Comment: I think you might be missing a conjugation in there.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I misread the indices, it's only working because his data is real...

Comment: Is it just me or is this slower than the original?

Comment: For the OP's value of `n = 5` I get a x8.5 speed up. But for larger `n` things even out, and on my system the OP's approach is actually a little faster for `n = 20`. Probably because this vectorized approach, especially without your optimization, is much more memory intensive.